# A different VM with name panamax-vm has been created already

Tags: docker, controls

I am new in Panamax, I've just installed it, but have got the following error message:

```
A different VM with name panamax-vm has been created already.
```

I have tried to resolve this problem with use of `panamax delete`, but it causes error above:

```
The panamax-vm does not exist. Please run ($ panamax init) to install Panamax.
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your kernel does not contain module which comes from VirtualBox. You need to run below command as a root (I assume that you have Ubuntu) :

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```